# Deserializing JSON into list

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I got some JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
    "1001": {
      "name": "Test name 1"
    },
    "1004": {
      "name": "Test name 2"
    },
    "1005": {
      "name": "Test name 3"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I deserialize this into a list that, once deserialized, will contain `1001`, `1004` and `1005`?

My code so far:

```
public class Data
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
public class Object
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(json);

foreach (var s in data)
    list.Add(s);
```

This, however, doesn't work.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: please don't create a class called `Object` for your own safety

Comment: Do any of the Related answers over there help? ---------> 

Seems like fairly relevant stuff

Comment: @Sayse the OP should be more specific, but in this case it's pretty obvious. It doesn't compile because he's trying to iterate over an instance of `object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to model your classes according to JSON structure:

```
public class Data
{
    public Dictionary<string, Node> data { get; set; }
}

public class Node
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

Then you can iterate over the items:

```
foreach(var item in result.data)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert it directly to a list.  The problem is that 1001, 1004, and 1005 are keys for your objects.  A list would not contain the numbers, but the names within it.  This means you'd lose some data.

What you can do is use dictionaries, and then iterate over those.

Class Data should include a Dictionary of another type, lets call it Name (so ).  Name would have one member, string name.

Answer (score 0):

Your model does not match your JSON. Your JSON says there is an object called 'data' that has three properties named '1001', '1004', and '1005', each of which has a property called 'name'. Your c# model should be something like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public Child 1001 { get; set; }
    public Child 1004 { get; set; }
    public Child 1005 { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    public string name{ get; set; }
}
```

You may want to consider using a dynamic object instead.